# Ionic - Twitter Bootstrap - fonts

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fonts, ionic-framework

I would like to create app with Ionic.
I want to use Twitter Bootstrap for some elements, so I install bootstrap-sass via bower.
Everyting is ok.

I set up included in ionc.app.scss:

```
$icon-font-path: "www/lib/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/"; //path for fonts
@import "www/lib/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "www/lib/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
```

In view, I want to use icon, fe.:

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
```

But I can't see "user" icon. I've got dot.
I don't have any errors in console, but ! I can't see download font in Network.

If I pasted into address in browser:

> http://localhost:8100/lib/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf

I can download file.

**What happened ? How can I use fonts from Twitter Bootstrap ?**

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. Remove:

```
@import "www/lib/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap-sprockets";
```

From scss file.